# how to parse a list returned by a link using php

Tags: php, parsing, curl

I do have this link : 'http://www.domainname.com/employee=name'
when I put it on the browser it return this output:
`["steve", "charles", "Micheal"]`
How do I curl this link using php

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "$URL");
$ANSWER=curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$output=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.domainname.com/employee=name"),true);`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I got this error message : `failed to open stream: No such file or directory in line 2`

Comment: I replaced the url with mine,

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is probably disabled. Check out user2378700's answer, if CURL is blocked -- I'd assuming you're on a shared hosting site where a lot of php functions are blocked.